# jQuery stops working after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which relies heavily on CSS3 animations. I am in the process of creating a script that will be the fallback that will work for those browsers that do not have CSS3 animations (looking at you IE...). I created the following script that will do the basic of what I need:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide All Elements to Fade Them In
    $j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4, #tile-wrap, #copyright").addClass("hide", function() {
        //Change Color of "Frames"
        $j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4").addClass("color", function() {
            //Frame 1
            $j(".frame-1").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                $j('.frame-1').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    //Frame 2
                    $j(".frame-2").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                        $j('.frame-2').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            //Frame 3       
                            $j(".frame-3").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                $j('.frame-3').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                    //Frame 4 
                                    $j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                                        $j('.frame-4').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                            //Tile
                                            $j('#tile-wrap').fadeIn('slow');
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

The first part of the script works without issue (adding the class of `.hide`). But nothing after that fires or works. I am stuck because no errors are seen and I assume I have an error in my script.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/VNfT2/1/) of the script with the rest of the code.

Note: I am not very knowledgeable of writing JS and welcome any ways to improve the script, please provide examples.

***FIDDLE NOTE*** Firebug shows a couple errors when running the fiddle. These errors are only on the Fiddle page and I believe are related to the jsFiddle not my code or page.

***What I am attempting to Achieve***

What I want is for each item (as listed by class or id) is to fade them in then fade them out after a delay then fade in the last div and it stays.

Comment: Your title doesn't make much sense. Also, titles shouldn't contain tags.

Comment: There must be a way to simplify that code! Maybe if you think about semantics you can reduce it.

Comment: The way everything is nested has blown my mind. I will need to figure out why it's nested that way before I can figure out why it's not working. ;-)

Comment: I think the foremost issue here is to improve this code. :)

Comment: **@Greg Pettit** Seems like a bunch of callbacks inside callbacks inside callbacks inside...

Comment: **@Lynda** Can you explain more in detail what are you trying to achieve? The demo doesn't seem to work for me, I can't tell what's going on...

Comment: @Lynda Why are you making class names equal to a function expression?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/addClass/. You can call `addClass` with a string (the class) or with a function which return the class. But you can't do it with a string and a function...

Comment: @elclanrs - I edited question to add what I am looking for. Basically I am wanting to create a fallback for CSS3 animations. The script will add classes to a couple items then fade in and fade out the items one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, http://jsfiddle.net/VNfT2/2/. There is no callback for addclass. Having said that. AHHH!!!!!! This is NOT the right way to do it. Hint: When you see more than 10 }); in a row, stop and take a deep breath. :)

Edit: There are hundreds of plugins to do this (google for jquery slideshow). But, if you want to do it manually...look at this: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VNfT2/5/

Comment: Thanks, I agree and would write it better if I knew a way! My JS knowledge is not the best. (I know enough to be dangerous.)  =>

Comment: I was just writing the same answer as you. Also, +1 for the hint, OP should probably make it more dynamic.

Comment: @Rune - I may make it more dynamic but at this point I am just attempting to make something as a fallback. The problem I have is learning enough JS to make it dynamic without bugging everyone on SO left and right =>

Comment: @Lynda well, a way to make it dynamic is this: Create a function that you call on page load. In that function, you get the first element in a div (or anything else for that matter). After that you do the `fadeIn` function with callback the the `fadeOut` function. The callback of the `fadeOut` function would then be calling the main function; the one you've created. Then it will loop it over and over again, making it dynamic. Tip: use `:eq()`

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/VNfT2/4/

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(document).ready(function() {
//Hide All Elements
    $j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4, #tile-wrap, #copyright")
        .addClass("hide")
//Change Color of "Frames"
        .addClass("color");
//Frame 1
    $j(".frame-1").fadeIn("slow", function() {
     $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
//Frame 2
      $j(".frame-2").fadeIn("slow", function() {
       $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
//Frame 3        
        $j(".frame-3").fadeIn("slow", function() {
         $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
//Frame 4
          $j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow", function() {
           $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
//Tile
            $j(this).fadeIn('slow');
           });
          });   
         });
        });
       });
      });
     });
    });
});
```

As I said im my comment, you can call `addClass` with a string (the class) or with a function which return the class. But you can't do it with a string and a function... See [api.jquery.com/addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)

And in your callback functions you should use `$(this)`, it's faster because this way you don't search the element again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that your callbacks aren't called since they're supplied as the second argument.

[`addClass( className )`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Description: Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.

```
.addClass( className )
.addClass( function(index, currentClass) )
```

Here are some tips:

## 1)

Try to only have 1 nested/callback function inside another function.

Refer to tip 4, then function `fadeElementsInThenOut` for an example.

## 2)

Don't repeat lookups.

Old code:

```
// Let's forget about the callbacks for now
$j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4, #tile-wrap, #copyright").addClass("hide");
$j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4").addClass("color");
```

New Code:

```
$j(".frame-1, .frame-2, .frame-3, .frame-4").addClass("color hide");
$j("#tile-wrap, #copyright").addClass("color");
```

## 3)

Use `$(this)` to reference the same element within a callback.

Old Code:

```
$j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    $j('.frame-4').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        //...
    });
});
```

New Code:

```
$j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        //...
    });
});
```

## 4)

Don't use a callback if you don't have to.

Old Code:

```
$j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    $j(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        //...
    });
});
```

New Code:

```
$j(".frame-4").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
    //...
});
```

Here's your code rewritten to fix the problems.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function () {
    var frames = [ ".frame-4", ".frame-3", ".frame-2", ".frame-1" ];
    var fadeElementsInThenOut = function( els, lastCallback ){
        var el = els.pop();
        if( el ){
            $j(el).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                fadeElementsInThenOut( els, lastCallback );
            });
        }else{
            lastCallback();
        }
    };

    $j( frames.join( ", " ) ).addClass("color hide");
    $j("#tile-wrap, #copyright").addClass("color");
    fadeElementsInThenOut( frames, function(){
        $j('#tile-wrap').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```